# parsing WebDAV propfind replies

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, webdav

.
Hi internet,

I am developing a WebDAV client, and need to extract the informations from the XML reply sent after a PROPFIND request, in C++
I must admit that the idea of parsing this kind of XML replies doesn't transcend me at all, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel...
So does anyone knows if there is somewhere a XML parser dealing with WEBDAV replies?

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

To try with WebDAV API like [WebDAV .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdav)?

On the web site of webdav.org I found a lot of links to software and libraries for all kinds of languages but nothing for C++ and .NET.